# Dynamic tooltip with textblock in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tooltip, textblock

i'm have some trouble with tooltip in textblock wpf .

After i completed 1 task and if task is error i want update error info with tooltip . **But tooltip never show when completed** . Please help me .
Thanks

**Here my code**
C# code

```
if (status == "Error")
            {
                LogCreateSite item = (LogCreateSite)gridLog.Items[rowIndex];
                item.ErrorInfo = "Error";
                DataTemplate template = cellTitle.ContentTemplate;
                Canvas canvas = (Canvas)template.LoadContent();
                TextBlock txtError = (TextBlock)canvas.Children[1];
                ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
                toolTip.Content = "asdfasdf";
                txtError.ToolTip = toolTip;
                txtError.UpdateLayout();
            }
```

And my Xaml :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="error">
            <Canvas Margin="10,15,0,0">
                <!--<Ellipse Fill="#FF5050" Width="12" Height="12">
                </Ellipse>-->

                <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16">
                    <Frame Source="../Icon/Error_16.xaml" />
                </Viewbox>

                <TextBlock Text="Error" Margin="25,-3,0,0">
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Cursor="Hand" Name="txtErrorInfo" ToolTip="{Binding ErrorInfo, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="14" Text="?" Margin="60,-3,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Blue">

                </TextBlock>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Why can't you use binding?

Comment: I was try binding but it not working with me :( . ToolTip="{Binding error}"

Comment: You need to have a Property, which has `OnPropertyChanged`.

Comment: You have example . Please give me a link :)

Comment: And if i binding with ToolTip="{Binding error}" tool tip never show but if i change it to ToolTip="error" . Tooltip is show error for me :)

Comment: What kind of control is "gridLog"?

Comment: gridLog is DataGrid :)

Comment: And what is "cellTitle" then?

Comment: cellTitle is Cell in datagrid :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to do binding for tool tip to show the error/message to user.

Please go thru this tutorial for wpf binding. [Introduction to WPF data binding](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/) from WPF-tutorial.

your XAML should be like this for a proper binding.

```
Name="txtErrorInfo" ToolTip="{binding path=error mode=OneWay UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

It is required to mention `mode` and `UpdateSourceTrigger` when you are changing the property which should be shown to user.

Comment: Thank you but  when i binding like this ToolTip="{Binding ErrorInfo, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" . Tooltip has't show yet . Can you tell me why . My code is updated in topic . May be i have textblock in DataTemplate .

Comment: `ErrorInfo` should be a string

Comment: Yes . Sure ErrorInfo is string :) . But error can't show :(

Comment: You need to have a UpdateTrigger method. Else you will see initial value of ErrorInfo. It won't get updated.

Answer (score 2):

Correcting your code, see this sample for how to show `ToolTip` from code :

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
        t.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        t.IsOpen = true;
        t.PlacementTarget = txtError;
        t.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;

        txtError.ToolTip = t;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you tooltip is show but tooltip auto show when task completed :( . I want tooltip show when user mouse hover error :(

Comment: Apply logic accordingly.

Comment: Now i have a task . This task if complete i show completed image and if task error i show error image and TextBlock "?" , when user mouse hover this textblock i show message error with tooltip :) . Thanks